# why keep only first order of Taylor equation

Tags: taylor-expansion, computer-vision

My post is to ask why in some applications it keeps only 1st order of taylor equation.
The question is from computer vision (LK optical flow).
The assumption is $$I(x,y,t) = I(x+dy, y+dy, t+dt)$$ which means the intensity of the same pixel in different time is the same.
(x,y) is the location of a pixel in an image at time $t$ and $dx$, $dy$ and $dt$ indicate the increment of each of them at time $t+dt$.

To establish the relation between two adjacent images, it applys Taylor equation onto the right part of the equation above and keeps only the first order
$$I(x+dx, y+dy, t+dt) \approx I(x,y,t) + \frac{\partial I}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}dt $$.
I don't understand why it uses only the first order of the taylor equation of this function. A second equation is whether it is a wrong typing that it intended to apply the Taylor equation onto the left part of the equation. Otherwise, I don't understand why the partial derivative of $I(x+dx, y+dy, t+dt)$ gives $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}dt$.

Comment: The math tends to work out more simply with a linear approximation. You could try keeping higher order terms and see if you can get a better algorithm.

Comment: Your second question doesn't make sense. The approximate equation that you wrote out **is** the first order Taylor approximation, although I would prefer not to use "infinitesimal" notation $dx,dy,dt$ and would instead use "increment" notation $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta t$ like this: $$I(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y, t+\Delta t) \approx I(x,y,t) + \frac{\partial I}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y}\Delta y+\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}\Delta t $$ If that's still not clear to you, perhaps you could explain better what you are asking.

Comment: Especially in image processing, high order derivatives are corrupted by noise and virtually unusable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks, Daoust. Do you have any online or pdf document talking about this. Simple things would be better :).

Comment: No, just daily practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding why first order instead of higher order, the answer in this case is *most likely* the same as the answer in every other application of Taylor polynomials: In order to minimize computation time, use the smallest order Taylor polynomial for which the approximation error is acceptably small.

When you are reading some work that uses the first order Taylor approximation, you are free to question the author's (often) unstated but implicit assumption that the error of the first order Taylor approximation is acceptably small.

Comment: Thanks, Mosher. You mean that the author believes the error of the frist order expansion is small enough for this kind of approximation if I understood your answer well. How did they know or was there a proof that saying the error is acceptably small.

Comment: Maybe, does this mean or implicitly mean 1st order error is acceptably small is based on a small time-interval as well.

Comment: Absent an ability to read the author's mind, if it's not explained then we can only guess the author's beliefs, and we can only guess how the author justifies the implicit assumption that the error is acceptably small. Keep in mind, such unjustified implicit assumptions are very, very common in sciences (for this very reason, one should keep a hawk's eye open for them).

Comment: @Arifle Regarding how did they know the error in the approximation is sufficiently small -- in this case (and in many similar cases in applied math), I think they just tried out the resulting algorithm and looked at the results to see if the results were acceptable. By the way, if you used a second-order Taylor approximation in this case, the optimization problem you end up having to solve would be much more difficult. In particular, it would be non-convex.

Comment: Thanks very much to both you guys for this clear reply. Can I understand that it is somehow a strong assumption and in a manner an emprical way to solve problem?